# Units in the last place definition

Tags: floating-point

I am reading What [Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

The concept of **ulp**s seems pretty straightforward. However, in an early example, the author makes a claim (in section *Guard Digits*)

That, when comparing the calculated value: **(0.02 x 10)** to the true value **(0.17)** of a calculation **(10.1 - 9.93)**, that the error is **30ulps**.

By the formula presented earlier in the paper, the error should be:

**|0.02 - 0.017| * 100** = **0.3ulps**, which makes sense to me.

Clearly, I am missing something rather important here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While illustrating the subtraction, Goldberg shows the result as .02 × 10<sup>1</sup>. This keeps the exponent that was used in the inputs and the subtraction. However, it is not the normalized exponent of the result.

In the example, the precision *p* is 3 digits. Thus, the computed result .02 × 10<sup>1</sup> could be represented as 2.00 × 10<sup>−1</sup>, and the exact mathematical result would be 1.70 × 10<sup>−1</sup>. The ULP of both of these representations is .01 × 10<sup>−1</sup>, and the computed result differs from the mathematical result by 30 ULP.

Comment: Ah - how silly of me. Coming from a scientific background, the notion of adding accuracy in the result never occurred. I guess this is part of the danger with FP. Thank  you for the response; very clear.

Answer (score 5):

Having 2 digits doesn't mean that 1 ulp is 0.01. The whole point of the unit is that it's relative to the precision of a particular number. 0.02 is **2.00 * 10<sup>-2</sup>**; 0.017 is **1.70 * 10<sup>-2</sup>**; there are 30 steps between 1.70 and 2.00 as

```
Err = | 2.00 - 1.70 | (10²)
    = 30 ulps
```

(Since these two results happen to have the same exponent, we're spared the difficulty of deciding which one "defines" the ulp, but we are *not* defining it by 10.1 or 9.93.)